# snappy-data with pre-build existing spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark-sql, snappydata

data  i will integrated my Spark cluster with apache Hadoop configuration its working fine, Then i started to integrated my spark cluster with Azure data lake storage , its also working fine, for the Reference I taking this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/08/05/accessing-azure-data-lake-store-using-webhdfs-with-oauth2-from-spark-2-0-that-is-running-locally/) for spark with azure data lake ,Then i need to integrate spark with Snappy data integration, as per the snappy-data Documentation we can use snappy-data Package

> ./bin/spark-shell --conf spark.snappydata.store.sys-disk-dir=quickstartdatadir --conf spark.snappydata.store.log-file=quickstartdatadir/quickstart.log --packages "SnappyDataInc:snappydata:0.7-s_2.11"

After executing this One i can create the Snappy session, But i can't create the Snappy-data tables. i am facing this issue on like HiveUtill package then Org.apache.slf jar issue also. If anyone One Knows How to fix that issue Please Let me know Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Couple of questions:

1. Which Spark version you are on?
2. What commands are you using to create the Snappy tables?

I can see that you are not connecting to any existing SnappyData cluster. Are you running it in local mode for testing?